# Function type in template doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I was playing with variadic template parameters using gcc 4.6.1. The following code compiles as expected:

```
template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
class Event;

template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
class Event<RetType(ArgTypes...)>
{
public:
    typedef function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> CallbackType;

    void emit(ArgTypes...args)
    {
        for (CallbackType callback : callbacks)
        {
            callback(args...);
        }
    }

private:
    vector<CallbackType> callbacks;
};
```

But to my suprise the following "normal" version that has only one "Argument Type" doesn't compile:

```
template<typename RetType, typename ArgType>
class Event;

template<typename RetType, typename ArgType>
class Event<RetType(ArgType)> // <- error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
{};
```

g++ 4.6.1 gives error as in the comment.

Anybody knows why it causes the error and how to make it work? Also, am I right in thinking the above code is a form of "template partial specialisation"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename RetType, typename ArgType>
class Event;
```

Expects 2 template arguments, `RetType` and `ArgType`, you only give it one `RetType(ArgType)`.

```
template<typename RetType, typename... ArgType>
class Event;
```

Expects 1 or more template arguments, `RetType` and *optional* `ArgType`s.

Comment: Seems like the compiler does think of RetType(ArgType) as one argument instead of a function type declaration which I meant. Wondering why it cannot just treat it in the same way as the variadic declaration.  And no, it's not recursion. My intension of using variadic arguments here is to forward the function type declaration and use function objects.

Comment: Kos: It's not. Removed that comment.

Comment: H Xu: I don't think the variadic version works as you expect. I think ArgTypes... will always be empty the way you are using it.

Comment: ronag, it works. you can try yourself. The complete version is too long to post here.

Comment: You can post it on ideone.com.

Comment: OK I have modified the post with a simplified version

Comment: Your modified post does not show me anything new. I still think ArgTypes.. is empty. Show a working example (with main()) where the code is actually invoked.

Comment: ronag, the main is like this:  Event<void(int, string)> event;  event.emit(1, "hello");

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make your own version of `std::function` for fun, it should look like this:

```
template<class Signature>
class Event;

template<class R, class... Args>
class Event<R(Args...)>{
  // ...
};
```

Why your first version works is already explained by @ronag, a parameter pack (`...` in template parameter) means ***zero*** or more. The code I gave above is still the correct signature if you want a `std::`/`boost::function`-like class (`int(int, double, char)` is a function type, that's why it can fit into a single type declaration like `class Signature`).

Comment: "...is a function type, that's why it can fit into a single type declaration like class Signature)."  -- So it seems the answer is, a function type, like int(int, double), is treated by the compiler as a single type declaration?

Comment: @H Xu: Correct, it's a single type.

Comment: Thanks Xeo, your answer inspires me with the root cause. @ronag's answer seems more straitforward for other viewers so I gave the green tick to his.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error is due to the fact that if the template is not variadic, then the cpomiler expects the standard form, that is class `Event<templateArg1, templateArg2>`, which is clearly not what you're feeding it with.

About the template specialization: I disagree, if I'm not wrong what you're doing there is to forward the declaration of the class `Event`, then effectively declare it just 2 lines later.

Comment: Does that mean if we want a template to accept a function type as the template argument we can only use variadic arguments? What I want is a to limit the function type with only one argument. I have modified the code so they are all definitions now.

Comment: Sorry have to change them back to forward declarations now to avoid confusing people with its purpose, as I have added a simplified definition for the specialised version. The general version cannot be instantiated because it doesn't ahve an implementation. It is by purpose.

Comment: "Does that mean if we want a template to accept a function type as the template argument we can only use variadic arguments?" yes and no. Without variadic arguments you have to create different templates for different number of arguments. It's pretty common. See as an example https://github.com/pisto/hopmodv4/blob/master/src/hopmod/lua/push_function.hpp

Comment: Lorenzo, yes that's what I was trying to do: To create different templates for different number of arugmetents, but only found the compiler didn't accept a function type declaration with limited number of function arguments. Thanks for the link.